# Check if a field's value is in another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains these values:

```
id
parent_id
type
```

I want to write a query that will create and store in a variable as 1 if these criteria are met :

- Each result's id shouldn't be a parent_id of another result (parent_id 0 doesn't count)
- The results should only be of type 1

For example :

```
Id = 1, parent_id = 11, type = 1
Id = 2, parent_id = 1, type = 2
Id = 3, parent_id = 4, type = 2
Id = 4, parent_id = 7, type = 1
Id = 5, parent_id = 8, type = 2
Id = 6, parent_id = 9, type = 1
Id = 7, parent_id = 0, type = 3
Id = 8, parent_id = 0, type = 3
Id = 9, parent_id = 0, type = 3
```

So from these data, only the id 6 would have a variable containing 1, all others are 0 as they do not meet the criteria

**In other words**, I want to verify that each of the current data does not match a parent_id of any other data.

**In other other words**, I want to not have `id` = `parent_id` and have `type` = 1.

How to do an if condition using the above? I want it specifically in an if condition as the if will be in a select of a bigger query.

Something like

> if ( id is in parent_id ( of all of the `parent_id` fields in the
>   database ), 1, 0 ) AS condition

I hope my question is clear! If you've got any question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable can be a separate select:

```
select t1.id pId, t1.type pType, (
     select if(count(t2.id)=0 and pType=1, 1, 0 ) 
     from tbl_name t2 where t2.parent_id=pId) cond
from tbl_name t1;
```

just make sure that `id`,`parent_id` are indexed, otherwise you will face serious performance penalty.

Comment: I want to do it in an if, because the if will be part of a select. And yes they are indexed! And I get a syntax error while executing your code. Also could you explain it please?

Comment: I'll mark this as answered cuz even if you do not reply to my comment, your reply solved it (gave me the idea). Thanks!!

Comment: I edited the code. It was missing a comma after `pType`. Actually the select inside a parenthesis will be shown in your resultset as a 3rd column. If you want to narrow down your result based on the condition you can use it in the where part of the main query: e.g. `where t1.cond=1`